# Не могу составить запрос Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Создать запрос, который:

- получает фамилии сотрудников
- получает количество выходных дней (суббота, воскресенье) с момента их зачисления на работу, например, если сотрудник был зачислен в прошлую пятницу, а сегодня понедельник, то у него уже было 2 выходных дня, хотя всего прошло 3 дня с момента его зачисления.
- сотрудники зачислены в июле 1998 года;
- отсортировать сотрудников в порядке убывания количества выходных дней. 
  Соответственно есть таблица Employees в которой есть last_name и hire_date.

Comment: это все один запрос должен делать?

Comment: Что вы пробовали сделать и что у вас не получилось?

Comment: @Александр, да, один.

Comment: @Vartlok, я не могу понять, как мне посчитать количество суббот и воскресений, просто делением на 7 количества дней задачу не решить.

Answer (score 3):

Количество дней суббот и воскресений в каком-то заданном интервале можно посчитать например так:

```
select 
  count(
    case when to_char(date'2015-10-01' + (rownum - 1), 'DY') in ('SAT', 'SUN') then 1 end
  )
from dual
connect by rownum <= (date'2015-10-21' - date'2015-10-01') + 1
```

Ну и все вместе:

```
select 
  last_name, 
  (
    select 
      count(
        case when to_char(e.hire_date + (rownum - 1), 'DY') in ('SAT', 'SUN') then 1 end
      )
    from dual
    connect by rownum <= (sysdate - e.hire_date) + 1
  ) holidays_count
from Employees e
where trunc(e.hire_date, 'mm') = date'1998-07-01'
order by 2 desc
```

[Sql fiddle пример](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/95c23/1).

Answer (score 1):

1. Фамилия. Ну это просто. Вытягиваем поле из таблицы, если такое имеется.
2. Вот этот заброс определяет кол-во выходных дней. Вам придется учесть, что здесь нет праздников и создать, наверное, отдельную таблицу под это счастье и написать еще один схожий запрос

   ```
   DECLARE @StartDate as DATE SET @StartDate = '10-01-2015'
   DECLARE @EndDate as DATE SET @EndDate = '10-30-2015'

   SELECT
   (DATEDIFF(dd, @StartDate, @EndDate) + 1)
   -(DATEDIFF(wk, @StartDate, @EndDate) * 2)
   -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, @StartDate) = 'Sunday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
   -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, @EndDate) = 'Saturday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
   ```
3. Ну тут тоже, не сложное условие

   ```
   hire_date> '06-01-1998'
   ```

   Сейчас попробую все это скомпоновать для вашего случая

**Обновлено**

```
Select 
last_name as 'Last Name',
(DATEDIFF(dd, hire_date, NOW()) + 1)
-(DATEDIFF(wk, hire_date, NOW()) * 2)
-(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, hire_date) = 'Sunday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
-(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, NOW()) = 'Saturday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Holidays
From Employees 
where hire_date> '06-01-1998'
order by Holidays desc
```

Comment: В Oracle нет функции `DATEDIFF`. У вас запрос написан для `MS SQL` помимо всего прочего...